# keep getting "Thu" when trying to pass a variable in strtotime PHP

Tags: php, loops, strtotime

I am trying to solve Project Euler's 19th question but I'm having a bit of trouble.

This is the question:

You are given the following information, but you may prefer to do some research for yourself.

```
1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.
Thirty days has September,
April, June and November.
All the rest have thirty-one,
Saving February alone,
Which has twenty-eight, rain or shine.
And on leap years, twenty-nine.
A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400.
```

How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
// In the beginning there are no Sundays counted yet
$number_of_sundays = 0; 

// Make the following actions for all years of the twentieth century
for ($year = 1900; $year <= 1999; $year++) { 
      // Make the following actions for all months from January to December
      for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
            // Get Unix Timestamp of the current month and year on the first day of the month
            $current_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 01, $year); 

            $get_day_of_week = date("D", $current_date);

            echo $year . ", " . $month . ": " . $get_day_of_week."<br/ >";
      }
}
?>
```

I'm not even trying to count Sundays yet, because it echoes Thu again and again.

I searched online and I found out that it's because I am trying to use strtotime with a variable.

So the question is how to use a variable in strtotime or mktime?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually call `strtotime`... [The results seem to depend on the version of PHP you're using](http://3v4l.org/aetV1), but the 5.1/5.2 versions only spew Thursdays for the first couple of years, not all the way. What's your PHP version?

Comment: Probably `thu` is equivalent to `-1` meaning it can't handle pre-epoch dates.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going on here. I tried your script and it works perfect for me. [PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u8 (cli) (built: Feb 17 2014 09:18:47)]

Running your code with the minor tweaks I did outputs this:

> 1900, 1: Mon
>
> 1900, 2: Thu
>
> 1900, 3: Thu
>
> 1900, 4: Sun
>
> [Many more lines]

Comment: What tweaks did you make?